# Program.cs file missing in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am a newbie and learning to code in C# in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I created two WPF windows and when I run my program it opens up without any error. Since I wanted to change my startup window to the second WPF window I was looking for the program.cs file as I found on the internet that this needs to be changed in program.cs. unfortunately I couldn't found the file. Can someone help me out locating the file.

I tried creating a couple of new projects but unable to find program.cs in all projects.
I tried repairing Visual Studio but no avail.

Would program.cs not be available in all projects?
Is there any other way to change startup window?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF applications, you change the main window in the *App.xaml* file. Simply, find the `StartupUri` in that file and change it.